# Не работает app:layout_marginTopPercent

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Всех приветствую.

Я делаю приложение на Android. SDK: 28.

Мне необходимо в каком-либо layout сделать отступ для ImageView от верха.

В интернете нашёл решение: просто взять и подписать атрибут `app:layout_marginTopPercent`, предварительно установив эти библиотеки:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:percent:23.1.0'
}
```

Но, к великому сожалению, оно не сработало.
[image: Не работает]

*И да, тот самый чёрный маленький прямоугольник - это то, что мне надо подвинуть*

Вот весь код:

```xml
<?xml version="1.8" encoding="utf-8">
<RelativeLayout xmins:android=" http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmins:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

  <ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
  android:id="@+id/imageView6"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Очень странные у вас примеры из интернета. Если хотите использовать `layout_marginTopPercent`, тогда родителем должен быть `PercentRelativeLayout`, а не `RelativeLayout`.